# What am I missing in order to create a dropdown list using simple-schema and autoform?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How do I get autoform/quickform to render a dropdown list?

I'm trying to do this using a schema with allowedValues but so far its not working.

Here's my schema:

```
AccountType = new Meteor.Collection("AccountType");

Schema = {};

Schema.AccountType = new SimpleSchema({

    accountType: {
        type: String,
        allowedValues: ['Business Account', 'Non Profit']
    },

    createdBy: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function(){ return this.userId }
    }

});


SimpleSchema.debug = true;
AccountType.attachSchema(Schema.AccountType);
```

Here's my code for rendering within the template:

```
        <div>
            <p>Account Type</p>
            {{#autoForm id="AccountType" type="insert" collection="AccountType"}}
                    {{> afFieldInput name="AccountType" options="allowed"}}
            {{/autoForm}}
        </div>
```

What else do I need to render these two options?

Comment: Why isn't it working? What result do you get?

Comment: Got it sorted thanks, dam typo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
{{> afFieldInput name="AccountType" options="allowed"}}
```

Should be this:

```
{{> afFieldInput name="accountType" options="allowed"}}
```

:/